# A subspace that isn't a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A vector space verifies 10 axioms, one of them being that $$(i) \forall u \in V, 1u = u$$ (V is a non-empty set).

A subset of V only has to verify 3 conditions to be a subspace.
$$\vec{0} \in S$$
$$\vec{a}+\vec{b} \in S $$
$$c \cdot \vec{a} \in S $$

Now let's consider H a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, with addition and multiplication defined such that

$$(x,y,z)+(x',y',z'):= (x+x',y+y',z+z')$$ and
$$c\cdot(x,y,z):= (x,1,z)$$

Since H does not verify the axiom (i) described above, thus H isn't a vector space. However, H is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$and it verifies all three conditions to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since every subspace is a vector space, thus  H is a vector space. There is a contradiction, and intuitively I think my mistake is probably assuming H verifies all three conditions of a subspace. But why am I wrong? Also, in general,
I find it hard to see how a subset of a vector space verifying only 3 conditions will also verify all the 10 axioms (since a subspace is also a vector space).

Comment: As folks list in the comments,  the reason those 3 are all you need is because you are using the same operations as the larger space.   Those 3 with the same operations end up satisfying all 10.   And you don't even need the first 1, as it follows from the third using $c=0$ (but you do need it to be nonempty, so might as well prove 0)

Comment: As general advice: it is needlessly inaccurate to say that "a vector space satisfies ten axioms". For one thing, they could be rolled into a single one, by conjunction. Also, if one slips into thinking about "axiom number seven", one will have great difficulty in communicating with other people ... who may not be aware of one's over-specified axiomatic context. (Still, yes, some instructors will insist on this kind of thing... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t use two different definitions of addition and scalar multiplication. They have to be the same for any vector space $V$ and it’s subspaces.

Answer (score 2):

The violation is this:

> "... it verifies all three conditions to be a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$"

These three conditions are reduced from the ten axioms you mention. That reduction is valid *assuming* the implicit context that $H$'s addition and multiplication is that inherited from the parent space $V=\Bbb R^3$. However, you let $c\cdot(x,y,z)=(x,1,z)$. This is not scalar multiplication as inherited from *any* field, never mind the $\Bbb R$-multiplication. So $H$, with that **different** structure, must go through the test of the ten axioms before you call it a vector space. And indeed $H$ fails to be a vector space as soon as you investigate the multiplication axioms.